# Using names() in a loop in r

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R and haven't worked my way beyond using for loops.

What I'm trying to accomplish with the following code is a loop that names the variables 1 to 400 for 30 lists:

```
for(m in 1:30)
{
  names(paste0("points_GW", m)) <- 1:400
}
```

I get the following results:

```
Error in names(paste0("points_GW", m)) <- 1:400 : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error message is clear. The result of `paste0(...)` is a character vector - not an object on which you can apply `names<-()`

Comment: You are trying to make 30 different variables that all start with "points_GW"? That's not really a great strategy in R. It's better to make a list of related objects. Maybe `points_GW <- replicate(30, 1:400, simplify=F)`. Then you can do  `points_GW[[1]]`, `points_GW[[2]]`, etc

Comment: Looks like an X-Y-problem. Why do you want to create 30 variables? What is the underlying problem?

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this would often be to have a `list` of lists. The separate lists can then be accessed by using e.g. `points_GW[[1]]`. If you have a good reason to keep them in the global environment, then an alternative is:

```
for(m in 1:5)
{
    names(.GlobalEnv[[paste0("points_GW", m)]]) <- 1:400
}
```

This is using the fact that the global environment can be used just like any other environment, and environments can be indexed using the standard `[[` operator. Another option would be to use `eval` and either `parse` or `substitute`. However, I would suggest that a `list` of lists is definitely the more conventional option.